# How to interpret JSON format in android?

Tags: java, android, json

I have a url which returns the following, how can I save the data in 3 arrays (Item1Prices[], Item2Prices[], Categories[]) on android? The item prices correspond with the months in the "categories" array. I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.thorntech.com/2016/03/parsing-json-android-using-volley-library/) but I need help in modifying the logic in onResponse() to work with mine.

I've seen some examples of this done but I am having trouble recognizing what is what for my case specifically. If someone were to help me get started I would be fine afterwards.

```
{
  "dataset": [
    {
      "seriesname": "Item1 Price",
      "data": [
        {
          "value": 4.72
        },
        {
          "value": 2.81
        },
        {
          "value": 6.18
        },
        {
          "value": 5.17
        },
        {
          "value": 2.94
        },
        {
          "value": 3.77
        },
        {
          "value": 1.7
        },
        {
          "value": 6.72
        },
        {
          "value": 4.61
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "seriesname": "Item2 Price",
      "data": [
        {
          "value": 2.49
        },
        {
          "value": 0.72
        },
        {
          "value": 4.06
        },
        {
          "value": 1.74
        },
        {
          "value": 7.23
        },
        {
          "value": 5.83
        },
        {
          "value": 2.59
        },
        {
          "value": 7.54
        },
        {
          "value": 7.02
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "categories": [
    {
      "label": "Jan"
    },
    {
      "label": "Feb"
    },
    {
      "label": "Mar"
    },
    {
      "label": "Apr"
    },
    {
      "label": "May"
    },
    {
      "label": "Jun"
    },
    {
      "label": "Jul"
    },
    {
      "label": "Aug"
    },
    {
      "label": "Sept"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @Boardy I've seen some examples like these but I am trouble figuring out what is what for mine specifically because I haven't really worked with JSON at all before.

Comment: Hopefully https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm can help. Its a full tutorial for JSON and Java/Android. The question is too broad to help, if you get started in getting to the bottom of that tutorial and if you get stuck working the examples with your code then you can ammend your question to get more help.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for the parsing.

That way you build annotated POJOs like:

```
public class MyData{
  @Expose @SerializedName("dataset") ArrayList<Series> dataSet;
  @Expose @SerializedName("categories") ArrayList<Category> categoryList;
}
```

and

```
public class Series {
  @Expose @SerializedName("seriesname") String seriesName;
  @Expose @SerializedName("data") ArrayList<DataValue> data;
}
```

and

```
public class DataValue{
  @Expose @SerializedName("data") float dataValue;
}
```

and

```
public class Category{
  @Expose @SerializedName("label") String label;
}
```

Then when you need to parse you use:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
MyData data = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyData.class);
```